# Why does casting to a float hits a hard error on STM32F429ZI (App_Fault_ISR)

Tags: stm32, nucleo, truestudio

Why does casting to a float hits a hard error on STM32F429ZI  (App_Fault_ISR)?

I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. 
I'm use a Nucleo Board, STM32F429ZI, on Atollic TrueSTUDIO

The Code

```
CPU_FP32 speed;
CPU_INT32U val = (CPU_INT32U)(0x20u >> 4u);
speed = (CPU_FP32)val;
```

The Assembly where it last crashes

```
080026f2:   bl      0x8001dc8 <BSP_Tick_Init>
51            CPU_INT32U val = (CPU_INT32U)(0x20u >> 4u);
080026f6:   movs    r3, #2
080026f8:   str     r3, [r7, #4]
52            speed = (CPU_FP32)val;
080026fa:   ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
080026fc:   vmov    s15, r3            <----
```

Looks like a move issue

The Hard Fault Detected Window shos

**Bus, memory management or usage fault (FORCED)**
Extra details
**Attempt to execute a coprocessor instruction (NOCP)**

This lands on  **App_Fault_ISR** which appears to be a hard fault

As far as configuration
Assembler,Compiler and C Linker have in setting have FPU enabled   (FPv4-SP-D16)
Hardware Implementation selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've not enabled the FPU, this needs to be done before any floating point instructions are attempted. You have to set bits 20-23 in `CPACR` register.

This [link](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0439/b/floating-point-unit/fpu-programmers-model/enabling-the-fpu) shows the steps required, I usually do it in my startup code.

Comment: Thanks, instead of adding assembly found std_peripheral corresponding function and it fixed it.

`SystemInit()`

Comment: What do I do if my STM32 microcontroller does not have FPU? Normally my floating point calculations work correctly but then for some reason it randomly goes into hard fault error, I cannot figure out what is wrong.